# Get IMap entries on same node as Predicate keys [Hazelcast]

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm using Hazelcast 3.6 IMap to distributed store large amount of data (I've tested on 1B items). I want to join 2 IMap instances by keys, but it seems there no any built-in functionality to do it. So, I'm using `@PatritionAware` to store entries of these maps in the same node if keys are equal and then use `Set<K> localKeySet();` of the first map on each member of the claster. After that I try to get values from the second map also on the same node to avoid transferring predicate keys by the network. But seems `getAll(Set<K> keys)` doesn't do it on the same node. Does anybody already have the same issue ? Is it possible to resolve it based on Hazelcast functionality ?

See code example below

```
public class PartitionAwareKey implements PartitionAware, Serializable {

    private Integer key;

    public PartitionAwareKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getPartitionKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
}




public class FindDataWithPredicateTask implements HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable, Callable>> {
 ...
    @Override
    public IMap call() throws Exception {
        IMap map1 = hazelcastInstance.getMap("map1");
        Set localKeySet = map1.localKeySet();

        IMap, String> map2 = hazelcastInstance.getMap("map2");

        return map2.getAll(localKeySet);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is an `EntryProcessor`. This EP also has to implement `HazelcastInstanceAware` to get access to other data structures. It still is important to apply data affinity as you already do to make sure data that belong together are stored inside the same partition to be accessible.

More information on EntryProcessor is available in the documentation (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/#entry-processing-with-imap-methods) and an examples can be found in our examples repository (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/entry-processor).

Feel free to ask further information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After implementation `EntryPeocessor` with `HazelcastInstanceAware` and sending a process to each node with invoke `hazelcastInstance.getMap("map1")` I've got `PartitionWideEntryWithPredicateOperation : cannot make an invocation on multiple partitions!`. The map keys are implementing `PartitionAware`, so is it possible to get only entries with local keys (from same node or same partition) ?

Comment: Is IMap::localKeySet what you're looking for?

Comment: As I mentioned before I want to invoke ‛IMap:lokalKeySet‛ on map,  which I'm getting on previous step. Please see at code example of the question. But in case using ‛EntryProcessor‛ method ‛getMap‛ throws exception as I posted in previous comment

Comment: Oh I see, uff good question. There is no official way to retrieve elements that belong to a certain partition only. Maybe you try to attack the problem with the wrong solution. Can you clarify the overall usecase you're trying to implement?

Comment: I have 1B entries in MS SQL and there are several operations like sorting, filtering with these entries. It takes a lot of time. I'm trying to make computations in memory with distribution these data in the cluster. Apache Spark makes these computations in 300-500 ms while Hazelcast takes about 2 min. As mentioned above question I have 2 IMap instances which first contains keys like predicate to take values from second IMap ( simple joining to maps by key)

Comment: I use 8 HazelcastInstances in the cluster. 2 min is a too long period to get joined result values. I tried to put keys of that maps to the same patrition with `@PartitionAware`, but when I invoke `localKeySet()` on map instance it takes 4 sec to get the result. I haven't any ideas what I can use to take the result in more acceptable time

Comment: Any chance to share code? I mean more than the code above? Apart from that you used Java Serialization which is by far the worst choice possible. If you like to share the code more privately please send it to chris @ hazelcast.com, I'm sure I can speed it up for you to give you a good hint on how to make those things fast :)